# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'spot1' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<[Spot | undefined]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

im just learning to use typescript with react and im having a problem with the spread in useState.

```
const spot1 :Spot ={
  Product :'Comptant',
  Currency:'EUR/USD',
  Sens:'Achat',
  Amount:'150.000 USD',
  DeadLine: '12/09/2022'
}
export interface Spot {
  Product : string;
  Currency: string;
  Sens : string;
  Amount : string;
  DeadLine : String;
}

const OperationInital : Spot={
  Product :'',
  Currency:'',
  Sens:'',
  Amount:'',
  DeadLine: ''
}

const Operation = () => {
const [operation,setOperation]=useState<[Spot | undefined ]>([OperationInital])

useEffect(()=>{
  setOperation({...operation,spot1 : Spot})


},[]
```

the problem i have is this

```
Argument of type '{ spot1: any; 0: Spot | undefined; length: 1; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): Spot | undefined; push(...items: (Spot | undefined)[]): number; concat(...items: ConcatArray<...>[]): (Spot | undefined)[]; concat(...items: (Spot | ... 1 more ... | undefined)[]): (Spot | undefined)[]; ... 28 more ......' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[Spot | undefined]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'spot1' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<[Spot | undefined]>'
```

what i want is to concatenate the spot1 to Operation

Comment: That’s a tuple with only one element. Did you want to make an array instead?

Comment: You've told TypeScript that `operation` will be a **tuple** (fixed-length array), but you're passing `setOperation` an object that isn't an array. (Also, inside an object literal, `spot1: Spot` means "create a property called `spot1` with the value from `Spot` but you don't have any runtime value with the identifier `Spot` [at least not in the code you've shown].)

Comment: yeah i need an array not a tuple